# Interpolate without looping

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let's say an array sig:

`sig = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`

Another array k which consists of indexes:

```
k = np.array([1,2,0,4])
```

I want to find an array that interpolates between `s[k[i]-1] and s[k[i]]` only if `k[i]!= 0 and k[i] != len(k)`  i.e

```
p=2
result = np.zeros(len(k))
for i in range(len(k)):
    if(k[i] == 0):
        result[i] = sig[k[i]]
    elif(k[i] == len(k)):
        result[i] = sig[k[i] -1]
    else:
        result[i] = sig[k[i] -1] + (sig[k[i]] - sig[k[i]-1])*(p - k[i-1])/(k[i] - k[i-1])
```

How do I do this without looping over `len(k)` by vectorization

Expected : `result = array([1.66666667,3, 1, 4])`

Because for `k = 0 and k =4` I did not interpolate the values were returned as `sig[0] and sig[3]` respectively

Comment: Show your expected result.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a (very) limited amount of cases like here, an approach to vectorize such code is to build a linear combination of each case and the corresponding calculation.

So, set up vectors

- `alpha = (k == 0)` to match the first case,
- `beta = (k > 0)` to match the second case, and
- `gamma = (k < len(k))` to match the third case.

Then, build up a proper linear combination like:

```py
alpha * sig[k] + beta * sig[k-1] + gamma * (sig[k] - sig[k-1] * (p - np.roll(k, 1)) / (k - np.roll(k, 1))
```

Pay attention, that - by the way `beta` and `gamma` are set up above - the calculations of the second and third cases can be combined. Also, we need [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) here, to get the proper `k[i-1]`.

The final solution, minimized to a one-liner, looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np

# Inputs
sig = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
k = np.array([1, 2, 0, 4])
p = 2

# Original solution using loop
result = np.zeros(len(k))
for i in range(len(k)):
    if(k[i] == 0):
        result[i] = sig[k[i]]
    elif(k[i] == len(k)):
        result[i] = sig[k[i] -1]
    else:
        result[i] = sig[k[i] -1] + (sig[k[i]] - sig[k[i]-1])*(p - k[i-1])/(k[i] - k[i-1])

# Vectorized solution
res = (k == 0) * sig[k] + (k > 0) * sig[k-1] + (k < len(k)) * (sig[k] - sig[k-1]) * (p - np.roll(k, 1)) / (k - np.roll(k, 1))

# Outputs
print('Original solution using loop:\n ', result)
print('Vectorized solution:\n ', res)
```

The outputs are identical:

```
Original solution using loop:
  [1.66666667 3.         1.         4.        ]
Vectorized solution:
  [1.66666667 3.         1.         4.        ]
```

Hope that helps!